# What's the easiest dough for a Lemon Pie that still tastes good?

Tags: baking, dough, pie

What dough would you recommend for when you need to wrap up a lemon pie fairly quickly?

Comment: This doesn’t help you now, but if you’re prone to need to make pies quickly, a trick that I saw on a cooking show years ago:  make your pie crust, then freeze it in a block.  When you need to use it, grate it on the large holes of a box grater, then pack it down into the pie crust.

Answer (score 4):

Well... Pie dough? Flour, fat, salt and water. I recommend lard for flavor and texture.

Alternately, a graham cracker crust can be had by putting the crackers into a plastic bag and rolling with a heavy rolling pin until fine crumbs. Then mix in butter, press into a pan, and bake until fragrant.

Comment: But this takes a while, I'm thinking along the lines of *gasp* cookie-based dough or some other hideous thing like it :-)

Comment: Hmm... Like a graham-cracker crust? I actually take longer putting those together than I do just rolling and baking the dough, but if you're so inclined then the steps are easy enough.